# SP 2013 My site Update-SPProfilePhotoStore PS command error

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, setup

I've setup a new my site page for a client on SP 2013. I'm having trouble getting the profile pictures to update. After searching here at stackexchange and google I see some info about this but nothing specific to my issue. When I run this PS command...

Update-SPProfilePhotoStore -CreateThumbnailsForImportedPhotos 1 -MySiteHostLocation https://my.companyname.org

...to import images I get this error.

> Update-SPProfilePhotoStore :
> UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException_Logging ::
> UserProfileApplicationProxy.ApplicationProperties ProfilePropertyCache
> does not have 5a932038-8da6-4009-aac0-4e4aa1e7013e

It appears there is something wrong with the UserProfileApplicationProxy but I'm not sure how to resolve the issue? Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Here are SP's log entries.

> 08/11/2020 09:48:41.80    powershell.exe (0x21E0)
> 0x4948  SharePoint Portal Server        User Profiles
> g11n    High        UserProfileApplicationProxy.InitializePropertyCache:
> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
> of an object.     at
> Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.IsCompatibleDatabaseSchema(ProfilePropertyData
> propertyData)     at
> Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.RefreshProperties(Guid
> applicationID)     at
> Microsoft.Office.Server.Utilities.SPAsyncCache`2.GetValueNow(K key)    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Utilities.SPAsyncCache`2.GetValue(K key,
> Boolean asynchronous)     at
> Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.InitializePropertyCache()  d88a8353-d8d3-4235-8eb5-137f167a1f88

> 08/11/2020 09:48:41.86    powershell.exe (0x21E0)
> 0x4948  SharePoint Foundation           PowerShell
> 6tf2    High
> Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException:
> UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException_Logging ::
> UserProfileApplicationProxy.ApplicationProperties ProfilePropertyCache
> does not have 5a932038-8da6-4009-aac0-4e4aa1e7013e     at
> Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_ApplicationProperties()
> at
> Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.CheckAdministrationAccess(UserProfileApplicationAdminRights
> rights, Boolean requireAllRights)     at
> Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.CheckAdministrationAccess(UserProfileApplicationAdminRights
> rights)     at
> Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileManagerBase.CanManagePeople(UserProfileApplicationProxy
> userProfileApplication... d88a8353-d8d3-4235-8eb5-137f167a1f88

> 08/11/2020 09:48:41.86*   powershell.exe (0x21E0)
> 0x4948  SharePoint Foundation           PowerShell
> 6tf2    High        ...Proxy)     at
> Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_IsProfileAdmin()
> at
> Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileManagerBase.get_IsProfileAdmin()
> at
> Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager..ctor(SPServiceContext
> serviceContext, Boolean IgnoreUserPrivacy, Boolean backwardCompatible)
> at
> Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager..ctor(SPServiceContext
> serviceContext)     at
> Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PowerShell.SPCmdletUserProfilePhotoStore.InternalValidate()
> at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdlet.ProcessRecord()  d88a8353-d8d3-4235-8eb5-137f167a1f88

> 08/11/2020 09:48:41.86    powershell.exe (0x21E0)
> 0x4948  SharePoint Foundation           PowerShell
> 91ux    High        Error Category: InvalidData    Target Object
> Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PowerShell.SPCmdletUserProfilePhotoStore
> Details  NULL  RecommendedAction
> NULL  d88a8353-d8d3-4235-8eb5-137f167a1f88 08/11/2020 09:48:41.93
> powershell.exe (0x21E0)                     0x4948  SharePoint Foundation
> PowerShell                      6tf0    Medium      Leaving ProcessRecord
> Method of
> Update-SPProfilePhotoStore.   d306cd8e-683f-0000-889b-61d33f68d601

> 08/11/2020 09:48:41.93    powershell.exe (0x21E0)
> 0x4948  SharePoint Foundation           PowerShell
> 6tf0    Medium      Entering EndProcessing Method of
> Update-SPProfilePhotoStore.   d306cd8e-683f-0000-889b-61d33f68d601
> 08/11/2020 09:48:41.93    powershell.exe (0x21E0)
> 0x4948  SharePoint Foundation           PowerShell
> 6tf0    Medium      Leaving EndProcessing Method of
> Update-SPProfilePhotoStore.   d306cd8e-683f-0000-889b-61d33f68d601

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out I wasn't running the PS console as the correct user. I opened the PS prompt as the SP 2013 Farm Admin and it worked.